# Setting website_url application property to blank via the API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Any idea how to set website_url application property to empty via the API? When I try to send an empty parameter, I get 'true' as a result but it does not update the property.

curl "https://graph.facebook.com/myappid?website_url&access_token=applicationaccesstoken&method=post"

This is to comply with the latest policy about on-canvas only games.

**refer to bug:** https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/140498756103463?browse=search_50d24fd418f5d6c41473620

Comment: looks like in all the docs you can only modify, and have to use the app dashboard for any delete / remove actions.

Comment: This is not a DELETE; that would be for deleting the application. Bah.

Answer (score 1):

Docs state that an array can be unset if editable, we can try passing an empty array and see if that does the trick.

**Create**

> To set properties for an app, issue an HTTP POST with an app access
>   token to
>   https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID?PROPERTY_1=PROPERTY_VALUE&PROPERTY_2=PROPERTY_VALUE2
>   using the same properties and formats as in the table above. Not all
>   app properties can be edited via the API, please refer to the
>   properties in the table above for an indication of whether a property
>   can be edited or not.
>
> **Array properties can be unset by passing an empty array.**

Comment: I tried an empty array, and got the error about the field only accepting values beginning with http:// or https://

Comment: same here, hopefully the bug will change things.